# Can't connect to the web

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, ping

I have 2 laptops. One is Windows 7 PC, another is Apple.
I also have a DSL modem and a router.

The problem is I can't connect from the Windows 7 but can from Apple.
I can ping the router without any problems from Windows machine, but can't do

```
ping 127.0.0.1
```

Does this mean my network card is failing?

Comment: Is there any reason why you thought the answer was correct but not worthy of an up vote? I just want to make the answer better if there something not right with it.

Comment: @PriestVallon, do you mean I should click the grey arrow above "0"?

Comment: If you think the answer was good click that. If there's any more needs to be added to the answer please let me know

Comment: @PriestVallon, "Vote Up requires 15 reputation". Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Center -> Change Adapter Settings and right click on the adapter you want to connect to the Internet with and click properties. Now click on Internet Protocol Version 4 and the press the properties button. Make sure Obtain an IP address automatically is selected and Obtain DNS server address automatically is selected as well